# Mail Merged Documents Created By Excel Macro Not Being Released By Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a userform with a series of toggle buttons, each one representing a different report option, in my userform. When the user selects one (or more) reports by pressing that report's associated button that report query is put into a cue for which the code will loop through to process each.
Within the loop, a Word mail merge is executed for that particular report. The mail merge is executed, the document created, and subsequently saved. Those newly created Word documents remain open. The preference is for the user to close those word documents by clicking the previously depressed toggle button corresponding to that particular report in the userform. This appears to be working OK.

Now the user has the ability to access these documents once created (and before being closed) and edit and print them. They print fine, but they are unable to save any changes. The user can click the save icon in the menu of the open word document until their mouse batteries go dead and nothing saves. However, if you go back to Excel, click on the worksheet, and then go back to the Word document, you can save it. (almost like doing so broke a tether between the two docs)

If the user accesses these Word documents from the location they were saved (ie from the directory) from a closed state, they open, and can be edited, but again, cannot be saved. That is as long as Excel is open to the application that created the docs. EDIT: This is not the case. Even with EXCEL closed, these previosuly created mail merged documents, although editable editable. cannot be resaved due to file permission errors.

What I have discovered is, if my Excel application is closed, these files no longer exhibit the difficulties saving due to file permission errors. It would appear that once Excel has initiated and generated these reports, that it has some "lock" on them. These documents, as long as the Excel application used to generate them is open, they appear not to be fully released from the Excel generation code.

```
Sub merge2(ByVal i As Long, ByVal rpt_od As String, objWord As Object, ByVal dest As Long)

    Dim oDoc As Object, oDoc2 As Object
    Dim StrSQL As String, fName As String, StrSrc As String, strFilename As String, myPath As String
    Dim qfile As String, st_srchfn As String, wb_qfile2 As Workbook, itype As String, isubresp As String
    'Dim wb_qfile2 As Workbook
    Dim HdFt As Variant
    Dim wdSendToNewDocument

    Const wdSendtToNewDocument = 0
    Const wdSendToPrinter = 1
    Const wdFormLetters = 0
    Const wdDirectory = 3
    Const wdMergeSubTypeAccess = 1
    Const wdOpenFormatAuto = 0

    work_fn = ws_vh.Range("N2")
    Set wb_nwb = Workbooks(work_fn)

    'create workorders folder
    myPath = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\WORKORDERS\" & format(ws_vh.Range("B17"), "ddd dd-mmm-yy")
    If Dir(myPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then 'if not already created ...
        MkDir myPath
    End If

    'close data file
    st_srchfn = "u:\u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\DATA\" & ws_vh.Range("N2")
    If wb_nwb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox wb_nwb & " is NOT open."
    Else
        wb_nwb.Close True 'saves data workbook after TYPE was updated for GS
        With ws_base
            .Range("B24:D24").Value = ws_vh.Range("A57:C57").Value
        End With
    End If

    itype = Right(ws_th.Range("A" & i), 2)
    isubresp = Left(ws_th.Range("A" & i), 3)

    If itype = "DR" Then
        fName = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\REPORTS\NG\DR15NG.docx"
    ElseIf itype = "DT" Then
        fName = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\REPORTS\NG\DT15NG.docx"
    ElseIf itype = "FR" Then
        fName = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\REPORTS\NG\FR15NG.docx"
    ElseIf itype = "FT" Then
        fName = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\REPORTS\NG\FT15NG.docx"
    ElseIf itype = "CR" Then
        fName = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\REPORTS\NG\CR15NG.docx"
    ElseIf itype = "CT" Then
        fName = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\REPORTS\NG\CT15NG.docx"
    ElseIf itype = "GS" Then
        If isubresp = "HPE" Or isubresp = "HPL" Then
            fName = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\REPORTS\NG\GS15NG_GSH.docx" 'Passive : Hillside
        Else
            fName = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\REPORTS\NG\GS15NG_GS.docx" 'Passive : Wloo Park
        End If
    Else
        fName = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\REPORTS\NG\GS15NG_GM.docx"
    End If

    StrSrc = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\DATA\" & ws_vh.Range("N2")

    StrSQL = "SELECT * FROM [DATA$] WHERE [TYPE]='" & itype & "' AND [SIG_CREW]='" & isubresp & "' " & _
        "ORDER BY [STARTS] ASC, [COMPLEX] ASC, [UNIT] ASC"

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With objWord
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Visible = True
        Set oDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=fName, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
            ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=True)
        With oDoc
            With .MailMerge
                .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                .OpenDataSource Name:=StrSrc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, LinkToSource:=False, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
                    ReadOnly:=True, format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & StrSrc & ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";", _
                    SQLStatement:=StrSQL, SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
                .Execute Pause:=False
            End With
            .Close False
        End With
        .DisplayAlerts = True

        'page break routine only for sports reports
        If (Left(itype, 1) <> "G") And (itype <> "DT") Then   'exclude GS reports
            With .activedocument
                If .Sections.count > 1 Then
                    For Each HdFt In .Sections(.Sections.count).Headers
                        If HdFt.Exists Then
                            HdFt.Range.FormattedText = .Sections(1).Headers(HdFt.index).Range.FormattedText
                            HdFt.Range.Characters.Last.Delete
                        End If
                    Next
                    For Each HdFt In .Sections(.Sections.count).Footers
                        If HdFt.Exists Then
                            HdFt.Range.FormattedText = .Sections(1).Footers(HdFt.index).Range.FormattedText
                            HdFt.Range.Characters.Last.Delete
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                Do While .Sections.count > 1
                    .Sections(1).Range.Characters.Last.Delete
                    DoEvents
                Loop
                .Range.Characters.Last.Delete
            End With
        End If

    End With

    Set oDoc2 = objWord.activedocument

    'save newly created document
    With oDoc2
        myPath = "u:\fff\ffff\ffffffffffff\fffff\fffff\WORKORDERS\" & format(ws_vh.Range("B17"), "ddd dd-mmm-yy")
        .SaveAs myPath & "\" & rpt_od & ".docx"
        If dest = 2 Then
            .PrintOut
        End If
        '.Close
    End With


    Set oDoc = Nothing: Set oDoc2 = Nothing ': Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if it would work, but once the document has been created can you try getting your code to save the document? if you can, you could add a save option form that the end user could use to save the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new Word session to generate the documents, but you never close them or exit the new Word session, leaving it orphaned in the background with the document still open.